# std::vector<T> with function-local type

Tags: c++

Why does this

```
#include <vector>

void f()
{
    struct S
    {
        int first, second, third;
    };

    std::vector<S> vs;
}
```

work with Visual C++ 2015, but not with g++ 4.8.4?

Comment: [I don't get any errors here](https://godbolt.org/g/A9igjx).  Please explain how it does not work.

Comment: Are you passing `-std=c++0x`? C++11 is enabled by default in MSVC, but not in GCC. (Assuming GCC 4.8 has support for this)

Comment: @NathanOliver [I do](https://godbolt.org/g/16Y6jE), it's missing C++11 flag. Not exactly sure why?

Comment: @Borgleader That is interesting.  If you go up to version 6.1 then it works again.

Comment: @Borgleader oops.  I think C++11 is on by default then.

Comment: Because GCC 6 defaults to C++14: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html "The default mode has been changed to -std=gnu++14."

Comment: @peppe Thanks for that.

Answer (score 8):

Ensure you are compiling with at least `-std=c++0x`.

In C++11, the standard was modified to allow for local classes to be template arguments (for lambda support). If you target pre-C++11, this won't work.

If you're compiling MSVC, it will enable C++11 by default, which is not so with clang and pre-gcc 6

See also: [What restrictions does ISO C++03 place on structs defined at function scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6415550/27678)

- [Demo (GCC 4.8.4) w/ C++11](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mJuMSCtZpmTXZiIr) (Works)
- [Demo (GCC 4.8.4) without C++11](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GBdZsrFcUgyKb3Hy) (Doesn't work)

Comment: Might be worth mentionning that this support is on by default in MSVC? (It's been mentioned in the comments but still)

Comment: "classes to be local to functions" That was allowed in C++98. What was not allowed was to use them as template type parameters .

Comment: I was going to ask why C++11 allows local structs. Didnt know that before. When you say "for lambda support" is it something going on behind the scenes when I declare a lambda or something supposed to be used with lambdas?

Comment: @tobi303 A lambda is a unnamed class type.  It looks like an expression but that is just syntactic sugar.  The compiler actually builds a class type with what you provide in the expression.

Comment: @NathanOliver: And to be slightly more formal, the standard requires that a lambda be a class "The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion
class type" [expr.prim.lambda]

Comment: @NathanOliver thx. So a lambda is kind of the same thing as a local functor

Comment: @tobi303 Exactly.  It is just a nice short way to be able to write it.  Think of them as throw away objects basically.  You really should only be using them for something where a named object really isn't need but a object would be nice to have.

Comment: That doesn't quite explain what lambdas have to do with allowing local classes as template type parameters...

Comment: @peppe: Consider `std::copy_if` - its predicate is a template type parameter, and a typical use case of a lambda.